# Persistent System on Memory-Stick

Tags: linux, grub, gnu

On our university we are used to have several GNU/Linux systems running as virtual machines for different courses. Because I personally do not like VMs for several reaseons, I have often 1-2 USB-Sticks with a system installed, like I would it install on a harddrive.

Last week, the VM of a friend of mine was not working anymore, so I copied my stick wit "dd" on one of him.
To my surprise it worked on his machine as well.

The stick runns just fine. But the boot proces was terrible long. Can someone explain why this happens. And give me maybe a suggestion how to fix this.

Thanks for your Answers.

PS: It's  not a pretty important, I'm just curious.
So I did not list the exact hardware or anything. A simple idea or hint where i could finnd the answer/reason myself is fine ;)

Answer (score 2):

USB memory sticks vary quite a bit in speed, the difference between the slowest and the fastest is pretty substantial. I asked Google for a benchmark, and [one site reports the difference is 3 orders of magnitude](https://usb.userbenchmark.com/) between the fastest and slowest (booting an OS is a seek- and read-heavy I/O mix).

That's presuming the hardware is similar; some machines just take longer to boot than others. As an extreme example, some (typically server) storage systems take *several minutes* to scan & enumerate their disks at boot.

If the live image uses systemd, you could try `systemd-analyze` to see if there is something responsible for the big difference, or if its just everywhere (because of, e.g., slower I/O). Useful subcommands would be `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`.